# Can the Sorcerer use 'Lightning Shift' while prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, sorcerer, prone, move-action

**Lightning Shift** is a 6th Level Sorcerer Utility Encounter Power that is a move action.

> **Effect**: You shift your speed.  You
>   ignore difficult terrain during the
>   shift.

If the sorcerer is knocked prone can she use this power before standing up?

Comment: [Related] [If a power says 'move your speed', what happens while I'm prone?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/13014)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**,

Part of the definition of Prone<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=141)</sup> is:

> You can’t move from your space, although you can teleport, crawl, or be forced to move by a pull, a push, or a slide.

**Lightning shift** does not use one of the forms of movement that can allow a creature to move while prone.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use Lightning Shift while prone, you need to take one of a number of feats or items:

In rough order from least onerous to most:

- Feet slot: [Floorfighter Straps](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1323)
- Feat: [Low Crawl](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2604)
- Acrobat's Boots and other effects: while using a minor to stand up isn't *exactly* shifting while prone, they allow you to shift on the same turn that you were prone. Still, not quite answering the question