# If a power says 'move your speed', what happens while I'm prone?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, movement, prone

I want to use the Battlemind At-Will power **Lightning Rush** [[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2634)], PHB3 p. 49, while I am prone, with a normal speed of 6, with an enemy that is 6 squares away, one that is 3 squares away, and one that is adjacent.

If each of these proc the trigger which, if any, are valid targets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, you cannot move via Lightning Rush while prone.**  You can use Lightning Rush against the enemy adjacent to you as the Move part is an effect.  Being unable to do it does not limit your attack in any way.

[Lightning Rush:](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=power&id=2634)

> **Effect:** Before the attack, you move your speed to a square adjacent to the triggering enemy.

Ok, so before the attack you move, what is [Move](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=505)? Luckily for us it has a specific definition.

> Any instance of movement, whether it is done willingly or unwillingly. Whenever a creature, an object, or an effect leaves a square to enter another, it is moving. Shifting, teleporting, and being pushed are all examples of moves.

It's common to confuse Walk with Move, but the two are distinct.  Movement encompasses any way that you go from one square to another, while Walk is an action you take which allows you to move.

[Walk](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=339):

> Movement: Move a number of squares up to your speed.

So is [Crawl](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=326):

> - Prone: You must be prone to crawl.
> - Movement: Move up to half your speed.

Alright, so Crawl and Walk are both examples of movement.  Seems like Lightning Rush would work as it doesn't specify **how** you must move from one square to another, right?  Unfortunately, the definition of [Prone](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=141) shuts you down.

> the only way it can move is by crawling, teleporting or being pushed, pulled or slid.

*Prone restricts the ways in which you can move.*  In the same way that Walk is prohibited, so is Lightning Rush.

By the way, if you were to allow Lightning Rush to work, you're going to make every charger in existence very happy as [Charge](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=324) specifies Move as well, not Walk, or Crawl!

> **Move:** The creature moves up to its speed toward the target.

Comment: If `prone` restricts you to `crawl` as your only non-forced non-teleport movement option and `Lightning Rush` allows you to "move" (and doesn't specify that you must `walk`), why wouldn't you be able to `crawl` towards your enemy as part of the power's effect? Right now I can't see the point where the chain of argument breaks.

Comment: @arotter - prone tells you the ways that you are allowed to move.  Lightning Rush is a way to move (via its effect).  It isn't one of the few ways that prone allows.  When you are not prone, you usually have few restrictions on how you can move.  Walking, running, charging and lightning rush are all options.  (Crawl is not)

Comment: Yes, but from my reading `crawl` and `Lightning Rush` are not mutually exclusive, since the power doesn't put any further restrictions on the required movement.
(i.) `Lightning Rush` allows you to use a valid `Movement` option to get adjacent to the triggering enemy
(ii.) `Prone` restricts your valid `Movement` options to forced moves, teleport and `Crawl`
(iii.) `Crawl` is a valid `Movement` option that lets you move half your speed while prone

Comment: However, if you consider `Lightning Rush` being its own `Movement` option in itself rather than merely requiring the character being able to take a valid `Movement` action, then you're correct. But your interpretation somewhat limits the use of `Lightning Rush` to characters with a fly/swim/climb speed since those aren't "normal" movements either.

Comment: @arotter - I think you aren't correct but I encourage you to enter your own answer.  I'd feel a lot better if more 4e questions around here had well written contrary opinions for people to vote on.

Comment: @arotter - Pat's point is valid:  all forms of voluntary movement are ultimately a result of some action: Walk, Crawl, Fly, Climb, Teleport, Squeeze, etc.  Consider the definition of "Speed": "The distances (in squares) that a creature can move using the walk action."  This clarifies that "normal" movement is still an action: Walk.  There isn't anything (voluntary) that is just "Movement" without being some action.  In turn, other forms of movement are themselves self-describing actions and are subject to Prone's selective nature.  Prone would have to say, "you can also Lightning Rush".

Answer (score 8):

No you cannot move. From Prone:

> the only way it can move is by crawling, teleporting or being pushed, pulled or slid.

Looks to me like normal movement is prohibited.

Comment: To be fair, "Lightning Rush" is not "normal movement" either. Now, "movement other than crawling, teleporting or being... is prohibited" would be right, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the answers here seem to rely on the idea that crawling is not a type of movement, but walking is.  That seems to be expressly ruled out by the quotes regarding Prone and Crawl, which state:

Prone

> the only way it can **move** is by *crawling*, teleporting or being pushed, pulled or slid.

Crawl

> Movement: **Move** up to *half your speed*.

Unless you're going to rule that Lightning Rush actually requires you to move *exactly* your speed, no more, no less,

> Effect: Before the attack, you **move** *your speed* to a square adjacent to the triggering enemy.

then being prone does not prevent the movement granted to the power's user, it just restricts the maximum distance you can move to half your speed.

All of these descriptions use the same key term.  **Move**.
Since specific beats general, only when specific actually *exists*, it seems that **move** should mean **move** in all three cases here.

Nothing in Lightning Rush rules out any particular *form* of movement (it doesn't restrict it to walking, for example), so any available form of movement should suffice for the use of the power.  Being prone simply restricts the maximum distance you can move to *half* your speed, because that is a specific limitation of crawl, and being prone limits which specific *types* of move you can pick.